# Vue Router - Set default query parameters

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm implementing an paginated list. Therefore I'm using query parameters like `?size=10`.   This query paramter needs to be always inside my URL (like /home?size=2).

This apporach is not working:

```js
const routes = [{ path: "/home", query: { size: "10" }, components: MyPage }];
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});
```

I thought it is instantiating the route with some parameters. Looking into the Routing section of vue devtools shows me an empty query object:

```
$route:/home
  fullPath:"/home"
  path:"/home
  query:Object (empty)
  hash:""
  name:undefined
  params:Object (empty)
  matched:Array[0]
  meta:Object (empty)
  redirectedFrom:undefined
  href:"/home
```

How can I set a default query param to my route?

Comment: I would recommend you to implement the paginated list with javascript and not with routing. Or is there a special usecase why it has to be via routing?

Comment: Currently our approach is vanilla JS. For reasons we are migrating to vue. I saw that you can  (and should?!) handle query parameters with vue router. For other usecases, like filtering the list, would be easier if we can handle it with query parameters and vue routing (we do not need to couple the filter components with the list components tightly).

Comment: Even if it could somehow be feasible to have default in Vue router, I recommend using a global state with either Vuex or Pinia to have this dynamic (end user would be able to change it, if he prefers 20 elements per pagination). Setting a default value in the store would be totally feasible too and more common as a practice.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. In the momenet, we are trying to avoid using a tool for statemanagement (adds more complexity, we are newbies). However I'm interested in some examples. Can u link them? Additionally, how could we achieve this without vuex/pinia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal using the `beforeEach` NavigationGuard:

```js
const routes = [{ path: "/home", name: "Home", components: MyPage }];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
}); 

router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  if(to.name === "Home" && !to.query.hasOwnProperty("size")){
      to.query.size = "10"
  }
})
```

The idea is to add to the route a default query parameter for `size` when it is not there.

Comment: This can be done more directly by adding a `beforeEnter` method to the route object. Then you also don't need to check `to.name === 'Home'`. Just tried it because I needed to set a default to `to.params`. And if you do `to.query.size ??= '10'` you don't need an `if` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this properly without defining the default value in every `router.push()` is probably with [Navigation Gurads](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard). You can use them to get the query-parameters that are currently in the url, add the default query-params you need and then return the new route.

Though I would not do it, this is probably the easiest way to achieve this.

And if you want to make them customizable via [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/)/[vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) you would need to set up a store and make a user input to change the setting.

> Note: Pinia is most likely the better option, because it is newer and will still be supported far in the future